# How can I load messages from Excel to SAP table T100?

Tags: sql, batch-file, insert, abap

I have to work out an solution for the following issue: My task is to import round about 2000 translations of existing messages to SAP. Does any one of you a simple solution how I can accomplish that, other than doing it manually with `SE91`?

I thought about solving this with an simple `UPDATE` or `INSERT`, but since I am a noob when it comes to code in ABAP, I would appreciate a hint to start somewhere.

```
    SPRSL   ARBGB   MSGNR   TEXT
    ------------------------------------
    D       /WMS    001     eine Nachricht
```

That is what i want the result in the table look like afterwards.

```
    SPRSL   ARBGB   MSGNR   TEXT
    ------------------------------------
    D       /WMS    001     eine Nachricht
    E       /WMS    001     some message
```

I have everything well prepared (Table with translation within the required structure, SQL - Insert Statement for each message class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in translation tool contains a facility to collect the short text of message classes, export them to an Excel file and re-import the translations. More information on this can be found in the [on-line documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_me60/helpdata/en/13/59b59da7934dc0b63996483ba3e327/frameset.htm). Since this is a supported standard function, I would always prefer to use this method instead of manipulating the tables directly.

If that should not be possible, I would recommend exporting the message class using SAPlink, then manipulate the XML file and re-import the message class.

Comment: Tanks, i will try that!

Comment: Nope, for this case, it 's LXE_MASTER... SE63 does not have an export/reimport facility as far as I know

Comment: LXE_MASTER Solved my problem perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I figuered a way to solve this issue. I created a LSMW - job with an empty Batch-Job-Recording of tx `SE16`. In the menuepoint "fieldmapping" there is a slot to code in ABAP. There I wrote that simple ABAP code

```
DATA: t_T100 TYPE T100.
t_T100-SPRSL = TRANSLATIONS-SPRSL.
t_T100-ARBGB = TRANSLATIONS-ARBGB.
t_T100-MSGNR = TRANSLATIONS-MSGNR.
t_T100-TEXT = TRANSLATIONS-TEXT.

INSERT T100 FROM t_T100.
```

Then I imported my translations as CSV in the LSMW. I only had to press run and all the data were in the database in the right structure.

Comment: Be aware that you might need to check the diacritics. It's surprisingly easy to read a file with the wrong encoding / codepage in LSMW...